# Axios POST request not working with MailChimp API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to post an email to my list on MailChimp. I am using axios and react to try and achieve this task.
Currently, when the request is made I am not receiving any response back but rather getting a (failed) net::ERR_FAILED.

```js
const handleSendEmail = () => {
            axios.post('https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/XXXXXXXXXX/members/', {           

                    headers: {
                        'Authorization':  `Basic properlivingproperty:${api_key}`,
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                      },
                      body: JSON.stringify({
                        email_address: email,
                        status: "subscribed"
                      },{
                      auth: {
                        'username': `SOMEUSERNAME`,
                        'password': `${api_key}`
                      }})
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error.data);
            });
    }
```

It is not posting and saving the email on my MailChimp account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In axios post:

- The 1st argument is the `url`.
- The 2nd argument of `axios.post` is the `data` that you need to post.
- The 3rd argument takes `options` (headers etc).

In your code, the 2nd argument is taking the options.

**So, change your code to:**

```js
const data = {
  email_address: email,
  status: "subscribed"
};

const options = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization':  `Basic properlivingproperty:${api_key}`,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  }
};

axios.post('/apiEndpoint', data, options)
  .then((response) => {
    ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    ...
  })
```

You can also provide 1 arg to axios post, in that case it has to be an object containg all info (url, data, options etc.)
[See here](https://github.com/axios/axios#browser) for details

Answer (score 0):

You can make a post request to MailChimp like below:

```
const url = "https://{dc_here}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}"
const data = {
    members:[{email_address: "sachin.test.11@gmail.com",status:"subscribed"}]
}
    
const options = {
auth: {
    username: "anystring",
    password: "{mailchimp_key_here}"
    },
}
const axios_response = await axios.post(url, data, options);
console.log(axios_response.data);
```

**Note:**
Replace {dc_here} with valid dc. example: us-21
Replace {list_id} with valid list id. example: 7762d0b7cd 
Replace {mailchimp_key_here} with a valid key. example: fd14c93dadd62130afc7ee406b45d3a2-us21

Above three detail you can find in Mailchimp website